# how to Handle OnCreated on each content type that has some part?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm building a module to add a navigation feature in all content items that have added the Navigation Part.

I what to handle all the OnCreated events for all types that has Navigation Part.

For now I've seen only concrete type handle. Can someone guide me? Thanks

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to do. Can you elaborate?

Comment: How about `OnCreated<NavigationPart>((context, navigation) => ...` ?

Comment: NavigationPart is not editable, it is generated automatically each time a ContentItem is saved. OnCreated will generate a previous content link and a next content link. So you can add a widget in the layout for navigate next and prev content in the same taxonomy

Comment: @devqon I'm in that way. But I want to handle the parent ContentItem of the NavigationPart instance, not the navigation part creation because it will be a part only shown in display not in edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is limiting your choices here. 
Orchard does work like that but works better when you think the orchard way. 
Have a look at this module that tries to do the same but for blog posts: [Next Prev Module](https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Mod.NextPreviousItem)

You could hook up to the parent through the part driver and do all your business logic there.

otherwise, if you store the values in the 'child' contentitem, you will have to re-save the properties if your underlying contentitems change; Creating unnecessary data in the DB and logic to handle it.

I hope it makes sense, nano :)

Comment: Your are right. I desestimated store in database next and previous. Not only because what you mentioned. Your adviced module works on selected taxonomy. But I think this module should work related to any kind of content organization like tags.